# How to make html input type choose optional file

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to make the input for Image optional, but I do not know what should I add.
Below is the main part of my cshtml file. I tried "value" but it does not help. If user does not choose an image, the image from /wwwroot/noiamge/noimage.png is chosen.

```js
$(".custom-file-input").on("change", function() {
  var fileName = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
  $(this).siblings(".custom-file-label").addClass("selected").html(fileName);
})
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label asp-for="Image" class="control-label"></label>
      <br />
      <div class="custom-file">
        <input asp-for="Image" type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="FLFormFIle" onchange="document.getElementById('FormFilePrv').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])" />
      </div>
      <span asp-validation-for="Image" class="text-danger"></span>
      <br />
    </div>

    <img id="FormFilePrv" src="" style="border:1px; top:20px;margin-left:120px;" />
    <div class="form-group">
      <br />
      <input type="submit" value="Utwórz artykuł" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ArticleId,ArticleName,ArticlePrice,CategoryId,Image")] Article article, IFormFile image)
        {
            if(image != null)
            {
                string uniqueName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + Path.GetFileName(image.FileName);
                var name = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + @"\upload", uniqueName);
                image.CopyTo(new FileStream(name, FileMode.Create));
                article.Image = "upload/" + uniqueName;
            }
            if(image == null)
            {
                article.Image = "noimage/NoImage.png";
            }
            Article temparticle = _context.Articles.Where(x => x.ArticleName == article.ArticleName).FirstOrDefault();
            if (temparticle != null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            _context.Add(article);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
```

Comment: You HTML was invalid nd you have TWO change events on the file

Comment: @mplungjan did you edited my code?

Comment: Yes. I made a [mcve]

Comment: What do you mean by optional?

Comment: @mplungjan when user fill up form, he does not have to click "Choose file" to add image. This way I choose static image instead.

Comment: @JakubKowal That's nothing to do with your HTML or JavaScript, that's to do with ASP.NET Core's own server-side validation logic. You need to show us your page/view-model class so we can see how you've set-up your `IFormFile Image { get; }` property.

Comment: @JakubKowal Also, you cannot use `IFormFile` without specifying `<form enctype="multipart/form-data">`, which you aren't doing, so it won't work.

Comment: @Dai How could you edit this code so that if user doesn't choose a image, the default one (/wwwroot/noimage/noimage.png) is chosen? To be clear Image is a string property of Article object. I have added create method, which is connected to uploading an image.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cleaner version

What do you mean by optional?

```js
$(".custom-file-input").on("change", function() {
  var fileName = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
  document.getElementById('FormFilePrv').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])
  $(this).siblings(".custom-file-label").addClass("selected").html(fileName);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label asp-for="Image" class="control-label"></label>
      <br />
      <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="FLFormFIle" />
      </div>
      <span class="text-danger"></span>
      <br />
    </div>

    <img id="FormFilePrv" src="" style="border:1px; top:20px;margin-left:120px;" />
    <div class="form-group">
      <br />
      <input type="submit" value="Utwórz artykuł" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful. How could you edit this code so that if user doesn't choose a image, the default one (/wwwroot/noimage/noimage.png) is chosen? To be clear Image is a string property of Article object. I have added create method, which is connected to uploading an image.